# Telerik aggregate result is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I want to show of summation a column in the kendo grid and I did it with aggregate (Telerik).
but the aggregate result always is null. should I do anything else?

Here is the code

```
gridBuilder.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action(actionName, controller, listInputModel))
                .PageSize(20)
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                .Aggregates(a=>a.Add(p=>p.lenght).Sum())
                .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Delete", controller)));
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but isn't `p.lenght` a  typo?

Comment: As @GaloisGirl asked, is p.length a property on your model? What does your controller action look like? Also, please submit a support ticket, they will be able to answer this quickly.

Comment: length is a property of a model. Action return data source result.